# Как налету изменить CSS чужого сайта?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Вопрос довольно специфичный, попробую объяснить как можно проще.

Краткая информация: есть программа, где запускается браузер Google Chrome. При загрузке страницы все возможные стили специально блокируются. В итоге загружается страница без стилей.

У меня есть доступ к консоли Google Chrome, где я могу исполнять свой JavaScript, изменяя HTML. В текущей реализации загружается нужная страница и моментально исполняется код (в `head` вставляется тег `<style></style>` с моим CSS, когда страница загрузится):

```js
var myCss = '.example_class {color: red}'
window.onload = ()=> {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('examplewebsite.com') !== -1) {
    document.querySelector("head").innerHTML += '<style>' + myCss + '</style>';
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что иногда стили не применяются (особенно, когда на одной странице нажимаешь на ссылку, ведущую на другую страницу (где и нужно применить свои стили). Если же изменять HTML спустя некоторое время простым кодом:

```js
document.querySelector("head").innerHTML += '<style>' + myCss + '</style>';
```

То стили применяются всегда, но иногда ломается сама страница (не реагирует на любые клики по любым элементам). Не представляю как гарантированно встроить свой CSS на чужую страницу, не поломав ее.

Comment: ` document.querySelector("head").innerHTML` не делайте это так. Создайте элемент `style` и добавьте его в `head` через `.append`.

Comment: Лучше всего для этих целей использовать предназначенные средства [в документации MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) есть пример по добавлению правил CSS